# PHP upload form doesn't accept .pdf

Tags: php, pdf, upload

For some reason, my PHP-upload field doesn't accept pdf-files. I don't get it cause I thought there is no selection made while uploading the file... Any advice?

```
$name = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];
$tmp_name = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"];
$add = "downloads/lkverslagen/".$name;

move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $add);

if(file_exists("downloads/lkverslagen/$name")) {

    $lkverslag = new LKverslag();
    $jaar = date (Y);

    $lkverslag->titel           = $titel;
    $lkverslag->datum           = $datecorrect;
    $lkverslag->link            = $name;
    $lkverslag->jaar            = $jaar;
    $lkverslag->auteur          = $_SESSION['user']['naam'];
    $lkverslag->teller          = $_POST['titel'];

    if ($lkverslag->saveverslag($_DB)) {
        $feedback = "OK";
    } else {
        $feedback = "NOT OK";
    }
} else {
    $feedback = "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: Do you have php errors on? What is the error that you get?

Comment: I get the `ERROR` feedback message. So the file isn't uploaded. While other formats like .doc or .jpg are just working fine

Comment: There are limits on the allowed size of uploaded files -- are you sure the PDF file is not too large?

Comment: @Michiel -- do you have php error reporting **on**?

Comment: @Michal, true. The maximum given by the form was 100000, I increased it, and it's solved :) Is there any way I could increase the maximum size? (If you answer my question with your comment, I can approve it :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to repeat my comment: there are limits on the allowed size of uploaded files -- the PDF file might simply be too large.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some things to check:

- Ensure that your file upload and post limits are not reached by editing `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your `.htaccess` or `php.ini` file. If you have error reporting on, you should see an error when they're reached. See this: http://drupal.org/node/97193
- Check for file upload error codes. See the documentation for these: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
- Ensure that your `memory_limit` has not been reached. Again, with error logging enabled, you should receive an error message about this. http://drupal.org/node/207036
- Check PHP's common pitfalls documentation and make sure there's nothing there that helps: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php

If none of this helps, enable error reporting and post what you receive so we can tailor our answers better to your situation.